# Howto implement a Webinterface to a Assembly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a assembly and want a Webinterface within this assembly. How would you implement this? 
IHttpHandler is one way, but its very anoying to write the html output to the Response.
Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like [embedding views into an assembly](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/)?

Comment: Sounds interesting, but this will not work in a Asp.NET WebForms Application, right ?  If i choose this approach, how does it work without a Controller ?

Comment: @dknaack, you could also take a look at [MVCContrib Portable areas](http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib/) in this case.